# string aren't passing between my activities maybe xml issue in android studio

Tags: android, xml

Please help me figure out why my string isn't passing between my activities in android studio. I ran this script on my phone but the string I'm passing from my main activity is passing to my secondary activity. I'm going through an android teach yourself book and I believe the issue is in my XML.

Here's my XML code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.owner.hour3application.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_secondary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.owner.hour2application.SecondaryActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.owner.hour2application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    if (activityButton != null) {
        activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
                startIntent.putExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE", "Hello SecondaryActivity");
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Secondary Activity

```
package com.example.owner.hour2application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE");
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    if (messageTextView != null) {
        messageTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There's no button in your activity_main.xml

Comment: Are you sure that Pages are switching as there is no button declared in your activity_main.xml

Comment: @RakshitNawani Actually there is I don't know why all of it didn't select when I was copying and pasting previously

the button code is this:

Comment: @RakshitNawani

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_second_activity"
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp" />

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys sorry I posted the wrong main activity. The issue was in string.xml the string name was wrong. Thanks!